# Listview item is not updating when there is changes in Sqlite Db

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, observablecollection

I'm trying to refresh Listview items if there is some changes in DB.
But only working method what i found was adding items to my List and then removing them and adding again using timer.

```
Contacts.Clear();
DbModule.LoadLine().ForEach(es => Contacts.Add(es));//Add new items to list from DB.
```

or using this code.

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Contacts).Refresh();
```

In list view I'm using [image: Marquee Text Animation]. so for this case when i use timer it's
refreshing items and ruining my text animation. I think I'm using INotifyPropertyChanged wrong and that should be the reason. Can someone help me figure out this one :D
**.xaml code**

```
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact}"                                                
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      Background="#FF2F3136"
                      BorderThickness="0"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContactCard}">
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Label">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonUp" Handler="OnMouseRightButtonUp"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.Resources>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />-->
                        <WrapPanel />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            </ListView>
```

**Main view model:**

```
    class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ContactModel> Contacts { get; set; }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Contacts = new ObservableCollection<ContactModel>();
            DbModule.LoadLine().ForEach(es => Contacts.Add(es));//Add new items to list from DB.
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var x in DbModule.LoadLine())
            {
                Contacts.First(d => d.Line == x.Line).Code = x.Code;
                Contacts.First(d => d.Line == x.Line).Batch = x.Batch;
            }
           OnPropertyChanged();
           CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Contacts).Refresh();
        }
}
```

```
    class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyname = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
```

**Contact Model**

```
    public class ContactModel
    {
        public int Line { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Batch { get; set; }
        public string Message1 { get; set; }
        public string Message2 { get; set; }
        public int Stacks { get; set; }
        public int StacksActual { get; set; }
        public int Units { get; set; }
        public int UnitsActual { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What is the code of ContactModel?

Comment: How is your app supposed to know "if there are some changes in the DB" unless you reload the data? The database won't magically tell it to update.

Comment: ContactModel : `    public class ContactModel
    {
        public int Line { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Batch { get; set; }
        public string Message1 { get; set; }
        public string Message2 { get; set; }
        public int Stacks { get; set; }
        public int StacksActual { get; set; }
        public int Units { get; set; }
        public int UnitsActual { get; set; }
    }` @emoacht

Comment: @mm8 - my plan was to get all data from DB and then compare them to contact model and if example: Db.Code != contact model.code than update Contact and Ui. I'm sure there is better way  to do that but so far i only now this way. and this is my first  app in WPF so could  be all my code is mess up.

Comment: @Multispeed You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in ContactModel as same as MainViewModel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding **INotifyPropertyChanged to my ContactModel** Fixed my issue. Big thx to **@emoacht**

Example code from my ContactModel if someone need it.

```
     class ContactModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private string _Code;
        public string Code
        {
            get { return _Code; }
            set
            {
                _Code = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```